# How to get WOEID with Latitude and Longitude values

Tags: sharepoint

i have latitude and longitude values, now how can i get WOEID using these values??
and then i have to get the weather forecast using WOEID.

am able to get the weather forecast statically, need to do it dynamically by getting WOEID.

[image]